# Cannot access a disposed object when using Background or Hosted Service

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, background-service

I'm am trying to use either a `BackgroundService` or `IHostedService` and then have it call another class to do database operations with a DB Context.  The issue I am having is that when I'm perfoming the database operation I get the following exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context
> instance.
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
>
> TargetSite: Void CheckDisposed()
>
> ObjectName: DBContext
>
> Source: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

I placed a breakpoint on the first line of the `MyBusinessService Update` function and examined `DBContext`, it showed both `ChangeTracker` and `Database` already threw an exception of `System.ObjectDisposedException`.  So somewhere the `DBContext` is being disposed of before `Update()` is called, I'm just not sure where.

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(...));
services.AddScoped<MyBusinessService>(); // or services.AddTransient<MyBusinessService>();
services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();

// MyBackgroundService.cs
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    public MyBackgroundService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        private readonly MyBusinessService _myBusinessService ;
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            _myBusinessService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyBusinessService>();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(){
        await _myBusinessService.Update(); 
    }
}  

// MyBusinessService.cs
public class MyBusinessService 
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;
    public MyBusinessService(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public async Task Update()
    {
        // ...
        // Throws Cannot access a disposed object execption
        await _dbContext.MyTable.AddAsync(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is rare case where you can use `async void`.

Comment: You can't *need* it to return a `Task` since the *caller* of those methods cannot possible access any returned value, since they expect `void`. As @GuruStron suggests, this is where you may reluctantly use `async void`.

Comment: When I use async void, I get an error: Cannot access a disposed object when accessing the database

Comment: You would almost certainly get *exactly the same runtime* error if this did somehow compile. You can't say "returning Task fixes this" since you can't even get it past the compiler.

Comment: So when I leave async void I get the disposed object error, almost all of the answers for this are to ensure functions return async Task. But if thats not possible, do you have an idea on what else could be causing the issue? This code is contained in a BackgroundService which then calls _run. run is initialized by                                   
    `using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                _run = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Run>();
            }`

Comment: Could you try promoting the `FileSystemWatcher watcher` from a local variable to a private field of the class, to see if it makes any difference? My theory is that currently the non-referenced `watcher` may get garbage collected by the .NET infrastructure, while the `async void` operation is in flight.

Comment: Still getting the error after adding `private FileSystemWatcher watcher;`

Comment: Why are you using that loop? How and where is the exception thrown? What is the *full* exception text? I suspect the way `ExecuteAsync` is used means the event handler, which may be too slow to begin with, may end up trying to access a disposed FSW. Or a disposed connection. That delay loop isn't needed and can only cause problems

Comment: The purpose of the loop is I need to continually monitor a directory for file changes, when a file is added I need to process it and add to a database.  The exception is thrown inside my _run async `Task ReadCSV()`. The exception is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed() and its thrown on the dbContext

Comment: @DevEng the FSW is doing the monitoring. The loop is only blocking the current thread. As for the exception you posted, it means you tried to use a DbContext that was already disposed, probably by your own code, probably because the DbContext was provided by DI and disposed from one call to another. Are you using a BackgroundService perhaps? In that case you'd need to create a new DbContext instance for each operation

Comment: @DevEng could you please include in the question all this new information that you mentioned in comments? The `using (var scope = ...`, the origin of the exception etc. This is valuable information and probably relevant to the problem, so it must be part of the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll rework my question

Comment: @DevEng I posted how to handle the events *and* how to handle scoped services using the file operation as the scope.

Answer (score 1):

FSW event handlers should be as short as possible, otherwise there's a risk of losing events. The `ObjectDisposedException` text is missing, so there's no way to know what was disposed. Perhaps it was the `_run` object? Something else? If it was `_run`, it's quite possible that `ExecuteAsync` isn't awaited and the entire class ends up getting disposed.

To avoid losing events, FSW event handlers should offload the actual job to another worker, typically through a queue. The workers should be responsible for creating the resources and connections they need. And finally, the application should actually await all of these things to complete.

Using a `Channel` makes this relatively easy :

```
var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<FileSystemEventArgs>();
var writer = channel.Writer;
var reader=channel.Reader;
...
watcher.Created += (o,e)=>writer.TryWrite(e);
```

That's enough to publish the events. A worker method can read from that channel asynchronously and do whatever needs to be done :

```
async ProcessFiles(ChannelReader<FileSystemEventArgs> input)
{
    using var run = new MyEtlScript();
    await foreach(var evt in input.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        if(args.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {
            await _run.ReadCSV(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

This worker can be used with :

```
var workerTask= ProcessFiles(reader);
```

To stop processing, apart from disabling the FSW we also need to call `ChannelWriter.Complete`. The worker will keep processing any remaining events :

```
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
writer.Complete();

await workerTask;
```

All these could be bundled in a single class :

```
class FileImporter : IDisposable
{

    FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
    Channel<FileSystemEventArgs> _channel;

    Task _workerTask=null;
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public FileImporter(string path, string filter)
    {
        _channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<FileSystemEventArgs>();
        _watcher=new FileSystemWatcher(path);
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes...;

        _watcher.Filter = filter;
        _watcher.Created += (o,e)=>_channel.Writer.TryWrite(e);

        _cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
        _workerTask=ProcessFiles(_channel,cts.Token);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=true;
    }

    public await StopAsync()
    {
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
        await _workerTask;
    }

    async ProcessFiles(ChannelReader<FileSystemEventArgs> input, CancellationToken token=default)
    {
        using var run = new MyEtlScript();
        await foreach(var evt in input.ReadAllAsync(token))
        {
            if(args.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
            {
                await run.ReadCSV(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        try
        {
            StopAsync().Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            _watcher.Dispose();
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Using scoped DbContexts in a long-running job**

Looks like the object that gets disposed is a DbContext, probably provided as a Scoped service through DI. The solution to this is described in [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) - we need to define our own scope and use it to create and dispose a new service inside it. To do so, we need to add `IServiceProvider` as a dependency in the class :

```
public FileImporter(IServiceProvider services, string path, string filter)
{
    _services=services;
    ...
}
```

The scope that would make the most sense when processing files at unknown intervals would be the file operation itself :

```
async ProcessFiles(ChannelReader<FileSystemEventArgs> input, CancellationToken token=default)
{
    await foreach(var evt in input.ReadAllAsync(token))
    {
        if(args.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {
            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope());            
            var db =  scope.ServiceProvider                  
                                 .GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            using var run = new MyEtlScript(db);
            await run.ReadCSV(evt);            
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if `MyEtlScript` is itself registered, we only need to request that class :

```
async ProcessFiles(ChannelReader<FileSystemEventArgs> input, CancellationToken token=default)
{
    await foreach(var evt in input.ReadAllAsync(token))
    {
        if(args.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {
            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope());            
            var run =  scope.ServiceProvider                  
                                 .GetRequiredService<MyEtlScript>();

            await run.ReadCSV(evt);            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your async callback event handler must have the signature:

```
private void OnChanged(...)
```

You don't start an async task here!

If you start the file system watcher every time you make a database operation (path of watching is always the same!!!), then it's bad design and an absolute overkill. Better is to cache the file events in a queue (encapsulate in a class) and process them later. You also prevent problems with loosing events, plus you have a better performance.

When you get disposed errors, this is can be due to declaring "watcher" locally:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("/app/Import");
```

The "watcher" may be automatically disposed.

Do declare "watcher" as a class field and start watching in the ctor or provide a Start() and Stop() methods for your FileSystemWatcher at your database class scope.

Regards